# manifest.webmanifest varible name and image

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, user-experience

I’m developing a PWA app that is used by multiple businesses. Each business has its own subdomain, and I would like to know if I can use a variable or generate manifest.webmanifest at the first loading of the page so that the data in it matches those businesses?
Knowing i'm using DNS wild card so all subdomains point to the same app and the correct business is extracted from the URL.

exemple:

**acoolbusiness**.myapp.com
will get a manifest.webmanifest like:

```
{
  "name": "A Cool Business",
  "short_name": "A Cool Busi..",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "orientation": "landscape",
  "start_url": "./",
  "scope": "/",
  "lang": "fr",
  "description": "my app description",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/assets/acoolbusiness-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/acoolbusiness-256x256.png",
      "sizes": "256x256",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

and:

**anothershop**.myapp.com
will get a manifest.webmanifest like:

```
{
  "name": "Another Shop",
  "short_name": "Another Shop",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "orientation": "landscape",
  "start_url": "./",
  "scope": "/",
  "lang": "fr",
  "description": "my app description",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/assets/anothershop-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/anothershop-256x256.png",
      "sizes": "256x256",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the way to do it using google cloud function.

in my index.html
`<link rel="manifest" href="https://mygooglecloudfunction.run.app/">`

and using that google cloud function:

```
export const httpsManifest: HttpsFunction = onRequest(async (req: Request, res): Promise<void> => {
  try{
    // get subdomain if exist //
    let subdomain: null | string = null;
    const callingUrl: string | undefined = req.headers.origin;

    if(!callingUrl){ throw new Error("req.headers.origin is undefined");}

    const urlElem: string[] = callingUrl.split('.');
    if(urlElem.length >= 3){
      subdomain = urlElem[0].replace('https://', '');
    }

    // get manifest as JSON
    const manifest: string = await makeManisfest(subdomain);

    // Create a Buffer from the content
    const buffer: Buffer = Buffer.from(manifest, 'utf-8');

    // Set response headers for downloading the Buffer as a file
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="manifest.webmanifest"');
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/manifest+json');

    // CORS -> dev change for prod use//
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    // Send the buffer as the response
    res.end(buffer, 'binary');
    return;
  } catch(err: any){
    res.json({error: err});
    return;
  }
});
```